# Swift CoreData using predicates with Array

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I need to keep array of Strings in CoreData and later on use predicates for filtering data for that array.

According to this post field type Transformable (with custom class [String]) does the trick and I can properly save array of Strings: 
[How to save Array to CoreData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825604/how-to-save-array-to-coredata)

However, I can't use predicates for this fields. Specifically, my goal is to find all items where at least one item in saved array matches pattern.

So, back to question: is there a good way of storing array in CoreData so that I can apply predicates for it later on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104566/core-data-transformable-attributes-not-working-with-nspredicate.

Comment: Yes, that post somehow answers. I can't use it however since not familiar with Objective-C

Comment: Another possible solution - to create another Entity with possible array values and create relations between my object and new entities.

Comment: Yes. Avoid transformable attributes if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an appropriate solution for `CoreData`

Don't put array as `Transformable` field in `Entity`

1. Create separate `Entity` with a single field, use that entities instead of `array`.
2. Create relation between main `Entity` and Array replacement `Entity`.
3. During runtime: find `CoreObject` of array `Entity` using predicate:

```swift
NSPredicate(
    format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(YourArrayEntity.onlyField),
    matchingString
)
```

4. Use predicates for searching your main entities

```swift
NSPredicate(
    format: "ANY %K == %@",
    #keyPath(YourMainEntity.relationToArrayEntity), 
    arrayEntityFoundInPreviousStep
)
```